# How can a path be stored in this kind of structure, and how to convert it to something else?

Tags: c++, c, string, winapi, type-conversion

I'm having a look at the code of [FastCopy](https://github.com/laurent22/fastcopy). I want to add some option so that files are deleted to the recycle bin instead of permanently.

The first issue I came across is the way paths are stored - as a `BYTE[1]` type. I thought it might be some pointer pointing to the real path, but probably not if it's just one byte. See below for the full structure:

```
struct MoveObj {
    _int64      fileID;
    _int64      fileSize;
    enum        Status { START, DONE, ERR } status;
    DWORD       dwFileAttributes;
    BYTE        path[1];
};
```

Any idea what it means?

My second issue is that I need to convert this string to some scary MS type called "PCZZTSTR" so that it can be used with a [SHFILEOPSTRUCT structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Any suggestion how I could do this conversion?

Comment: On a wild guess, could the `path[1]` variable be used as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274472/c-double-linked-list-with-abstract-data-type (see accepted answer)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable Sized Struct C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688471/variable-sized-struct-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one-element array `path[1]` at the end of that `struct` is just a general C trick to implement variable sized structures. Prior to the C99 standard, variable-sized structures were not permitted in the C language, so programmers implemented it this way.

The byte sequence that stores the path begins at the first element of that array (`path[0]`), but more memory is allocated for the structure than `sizeof(MoveObj)`, so the array itself is more than one byte long. If the length of the array is not stored in the struct, I guess it's zero-terminated.

PCZZTSTR may sound scary, but essentially it's just a simple C-style string of `TCHAR`s, which is terminated with *two* `'\0'` characters. P (pointer to a), CZ (C-style, zero-terminated) Z (doubly zero-terminated), T ([TCHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc842072.aspx)), STR (string).

You have to convert the bytes in `path` to `TCHAR`s (which are normal `char`s in older platforms and `WCHAR`s in modern, Unicode-based Windowses), put yet another `\0` at the end of the string, and you got the `PCZZTSTR`.